# Query by custom field and group by custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I have two custom fields one called `movie` and another `year`. I would like to make a query wp that returns me the movie grouped by year; I want one movie a year.

I tried this here.

```
function query_group_by_filter($groupby)
    {
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->postmeta . '.meta_key = "year"';
    }

add_filter('posts_groupby', 'query_group_by_filter');
$movies = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'movies', // name of custom field
            'value' => "{$post_id}",
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
));
remove_filter('posts_groupby', 'query_group_by_filter');
```

but this is not working what my mistake?

```
+---------+----+---------+----------+-----------------------+--+
| post_id | id | meta_id | meta_key |      meta_value       |  |
+---------+----+---------+----------+-----------------------+--+
|       9 |  9 |      10 | movie    | 264                   |  |
|       9 |  9 |      12 | year     | a:1:{i:0;s:1:"1991";} |  |
|      10 | 10 |      13 | movie    | 264                   |  |
|      10 | 10 |      14 | year     | a:1:{i:0;s:1:"1991";} |  |
|      11 | 11 |      15 | movie    | 300                   |  |
|      11 | 11 |      16 | year     | a:1:{i:0;s:1:"2018";  |  |
|      13 | 13 |      17 | movie    | 300                   |  |
|      13 | 13 |      18 | year     | a:1:{i:0;s:1:"2018";  |  |
+---------+----+---------+----------+-----------------------+--+
```

I wanted the movie and year values to be grouped and return the values of meta_value

```
9 movie 264
9 year 1991

13 movie 300
13 year 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

To give an accurate answer there is not enough data, what exactly lies in the custom fields and what specific result you want to get. But I have a suspicion that you do not need an additional filter and you need to try the "Query Posts by Several (two or more) Custom Field Values". Here is a good article on this topic: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/meta_query.html

Comment: That did not work for me. I put more information about the data